# How to split numbers from one cell to make it look like Mac address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to split the data from one cell to 8 rows in excel

For example:
There is given long data in one cell: `65178492194051241284...`
The sorted values should look like:

```
65:17:84:92
40:51:24:12
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Excel offers multiple options to help you build your own formula

LEFT is used to extract characters from the LEFT of the string (also MID might be useful in your case)
[image]
https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/substring.html

Combining LEFT/MID with CONCATENATE you should be able to produce the expected output

[image]

https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excelformulas/using-concatenate-to-combine-names/1/

Something similar to

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,2),':',MID(A1,2,2),':', MID(A1,4,2),.... )
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `Excel365` then could try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,MID(INDEX(MID($A$1,SEQUENCE(INT(LEN($A$1)/8)+1,,1,8),8),ROW(1:1)),{1,3,5,7},2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will only work in Excel 365:

```
=MID(TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)/2,1,2),2)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)/8,, 0)*12+1,11)
```

Or if you want a more readable (and slightly faster running) version:

```
=LET( t,A1,
     L, LEN( t ),
     S, TEXTJOIN( ":", TRUE, MID( t, SEQUENCE( 1, L / 2, 1, 2 ), 2) ),
     MID( S, SEQUENCE( L/8,, 0 )*12 + 1, 11 ) )
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

With Microsoft Excel 365 you can use:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=TEXT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)/8,,,8),8),"00\:00\:00\:00")
```

---

If you haven't always have an exact multiple of 8 characters you should nest `FLOOR()`:

```
=TEXT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(FLOOR(LEN(A1)/8,1),,,8),8),"00\:00\:00\:00")
```

Comment: If MAC address has hexadecimal character like `abcdefgh` then `TEXT()` formula will fail.

Comment: @Harun24hr, Question title is: How to split *numbers* (so a numeric value) to make it *look* like a Mac-address. So I guess it's fine for OP.

Comment: Neat answer as always. I believe Sequence will ignore any fraction part of the number of rows, so I would say the first formula should suffice. If you didn't have Excel 365, just a pull-down formula I guess like =TEXT(MID(A$1,ROW(A1)*8-7,8),"00\:00\:00\:00")